# Is any map with calculated NDVI available online?

Tags: ndvi, satellite

Is there any map which has NDVI calculated?

Where can I get highest multispectral satellite image which could be zoom to very large extent?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools that can calculate NDVI, but it also depends on which territory you need to analyze and which dataset is the best fit.

You can use [this tool](https://eos.com/landviewer/?s=CBERS4(PAN10M)&lat=-28.06384&lng=-54.11307&z=14&id=CBERS_4_PAN10M_20180617_161_131_L2&b=NIR,Red&expression=(NIR-Red)%2F(NIR%2BRed)&anti) to get NDVI from Landsat 8 (5m per pixel; worldwide), Sentinel-2 (10m per pixel; worldwide), CBERS-4 images (multispectral, 10m per pixel; North and South America, Africa). 10 pics are available for free analysis and download daily but images under 5m/pixel resolution are to be paid.

Comment: I have worked on Both Sentinel-2 and Landsat 8 Images but due to less spatial resolution i am unable to zoom as ndvi gets blur . I have also use pan sharping but results are not good. IS there any way to solve this problem

Comment: Well, in that case maybe it's worth going for high-res aerial or drone imagery but I'm not sure if there are any resources where you can get them free. Price starts at 5$ per sq.km.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the highest resolution for a weekly NDVI product is the [PROBA-V 100m](http://www.vito-eodata.be) (approximately one image every 5 days). It is provided with a one month delay as a top of canopy NDVI product. Of course, you can also process Sentinel-2 or Landsat 8 images, but for a global extent you would need high performance computing infrastructure.

If you are looking for historical gap filled time series, a smoothed time serie of NDVI is available from the [ESA Land cover CCI](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php) project. It is global with a spatial resolution of 300 m.

Comment: I have worked on Both Sentinel-2 and Landsat 8 Images but due to less spatial resolution i am unable to zoom as ndvi gets blur .
I have also use pan sharping but results are not good